# How do I place elemtents from a query underneath another query's elements

Tags: php, html, mysql

To make my question more clear to you. I have 2 query's, 1 for head article and the other for subarticles. I need it to work so that everytime I add something it gets added to the div. Now I've got only one row working with 
**all** of the articles in it. The other rows do work but don't have any of their articles because I don't know how to link them to their mainarticle.
My query's:
(Some of this is without html code so if it doesn't fully make sense to you, its only the php that was important.)

```
   $content = "SELECT * FROM snm_content WHERE state = 1 AND catid = ".$cat['id']."  ORDER 
               BY ordering";
   $contentcon = $conn->query($content);

    $cat = "SELECT * FROM snm_categories WHERE published = 1 AND id NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7)";
    $catcon = $conn->query($cat);

<?php while($cat = $catcon->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
  <?php while($content = $contentcon->fetch_assoc()){
    $contentinfoimages = $content['images'];
    $contentinfoimg = json_decode($contentinfoimages);
    $imgprev = $contentinfoimg->image_intro;
    $image = 'cms/'.$imgprev;
    echo $image;
    ?>
    <?php } ?>                          
<?php } ?>
```

Eventually I found a solution. Thanks to @david, he made me think about how i could retrieve the items on id. I did this with simply placing my sql code for $content in the loop and detect on the id of the main-item.

```
 <div class="recentwork_carousel__crsl-wrapper">
   <ul class="recent_works3 fixclear recentwork_carousel__crsl">
     <?php $content = "SELECT * FROM snm_content WHERE state = 1 AND catid = ".$cat['id']."  ORDER 
           BY ordering";
           $contentcon = $conn->query($content);
           while($content = $contentcon->fetch_assoc()){
             $contentinfoimages = $content['images'];
             $contentinfoimg = json_decode($contentinfoimages);
             $imgprev = $contentinfoimg->image_intro;
             $image = 'cms/'.$imgprev;
                                ?>
```

Comment: Probably, you have to put another loop with gathering data into the first loop. But I do not see where the subarticles should come from... additionally, the posted code wouldn't work as the query in the first line is invalid

Comment: The code itself is pretty unclear, but what you're describing should be straightforward enough.  Generally one would issue a single query to get the joined results of items and sub-items, or at worst two queries to get each set separately.  Then the loops which build the output would loop over those results and write them to the page.  For example, if you have two result sets, your outer loop would print the items and your inner loop would print the sub-items for the given item.

Comment: @David And i have done that. I put the entire row in a loop and returns the amount of head-items and the sub-items have a loop within the head-item loop. I simply don't know how I can detect a new row and by that new items which I have a possible Inner Join link for in the database. I'm still new to SQL..

Comment: @StefanTanis: What do you mean by "detect a new row"?  It's not clear what you're actually asking here or what the actual problem is.

Comment: @david On each item there's sub-items. So each item gets a row. Only problem is that the first row only gets all of the sub-items and that leaves the other items remaining empty.

Comment: @StefanTanis: You have *a lot* of code here, and most of it is just HTML markup unrelated to the logic of your queries and loops.  Reducing the problem will likely make it easier to see what's going on.  But in particular, look at your loop for printing the sub-items.  In that loop you would check if any given sub-item *should* be printed for the "current" item.  An `if` statement checking an `id` value of some kind for example.  Draw out the logic in pen and paper first if you need to.  The inner loop needs to check the item it's printing to see if it should print it or not.

Comment: @David: Thanks for the help. Really made me think about what I was missing and I found a solution. I put this solution in the latest edit.